# Why do I get the following error using pipe operator in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rjava, rlang, magrittr

How do I resolve the following error:

> Error in dots_values(...) : object 'rlang_dots_values' not found

I'm getting this error when executing a statement like this:

```
dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(col_name1 = ifelse(col_name2 > 201952, 0.875, col_name1))
```

**Note:** I have already tried to update and reinstall rlang, rjava, dplyr, magrittr, along with my system's JDK.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dataset)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dataset, 20))`.

Comment: check that the types of your variables are as expected: `class(dataset);class(mutate);class(col_name1);class(col_name2)`). This could be due to a variable being a function or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is mostly caused due to security limitation on your workstation as R packages can only run to packages installed on the following path C:\R\R-[R version]\library.

You can either contact your administrator and change the privileges on your workstation or install packages only to this path C:\R\R-[R version]\library.

**Reference:** https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-object-rlang-dots-list-not-found/10555/3